# How to import from another ipynb file in EMR jupyter notebook which runs a PySpark kernel?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I'm using jupyter notebook on AWS EMR to run PySpark, and is having trouble importing modules from another file. I tried a couple methods that I searched on stackoverflow, none worked. More specifically, I tried the following (here I have a notebook named "include.ipynb" in the same directory as the notebook that runs the import statements):

[image]

Both of these methods worked in jupyter notebook on my local computer. Why aren't they working on AWS?

Comment: Importing other ipynb file should work in EMR version 5.29. Could you try that version?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install these packages in your EMR explicitly using Pip or conda. Your local has those packages installed already.